# Ordenar as chaves de um objeto simulando ORDER BY NOME ASC

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em mysql no comando `SELECT * FROM minha-tabela ORDER BY nome ASC` a lista será retornada com todos os resultados ordenados de forma crescente com base na coluna `nome`, eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer o mesmo com um objeto js;
Exemplo:

```
Object
   1: Object
      nome: "Batista"
   2: Object
      nome: "Thiago"
   3: Object
      nome: "Joana"
   4: Object
      nome: "Ana"
```

Qual seria a função para reordenar as chaves do meu objeto por ordem alfabética com base na coluna `nome` para que o mesmo ficasse dessa forma:

```
Object
   1: Object
      nome: "Ana"
   2: Object
      nome: "Batista"
   3: Object
      nome: "Joana"
   4: Object
      nome: "Thiago"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo comando [**sort**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) fazendo a comparação da seguinte forma:

```js
var obj = [{nome: "Batista"}, {nome: "Thiago"},
           {nome: "Joana"},{nome: "Ana"}];

//console.log(obj); // antes

obj.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = a.nome.toLowerCase();
    var bb = b.nome.toLowerCase(); 
    if(aa < bb) return -1;
    if(aa > bb) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(obj); // depois
```

Se no caso em particular for um objeto com vários objetos dentro, exemplo:

> `{0: {name:'a'}, 1: {name:'c'}, 2: {name:'b'}}`

tem a maneira de pegar esses valores e tranformar em `array` com `Object.values` e aplicar o mesmo procedimento com o método `sort`, afinal é um `array`:

```js
var obj = {0: {name:'a'}, 1: {name:'c'}, 2: {name:'b'}};

var objAsc = Object.values(obj).sort((a,b) => {
 if (a.name<b.name) return -1;
 if (a.name>b.name) return 1;
 return 0; 
});

console.log(objAsc);
```

***Referencias:***

- [JavaScript Array sort() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)
- [Using an alphabetical sort()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0220__Array/Usinganalphabeticalsortmethodonstrings.htm)

Comment: Isso funciona para Objects? Pois estou testando aqui e diz object.sort is not a function, ou eu tenho que converter meu object para array?

Comment: Tem como você mostrar @LeoLetto o seu código na integra? No meu exemplo é um `array` de **objetos**

Comment: Acho que ai está o problema, pois o meu não é um array de objetos, e sim um objeto com outros objetos dentro

Comment: @LeoLetto eu quero ver esse Objeto de Objeto tem como colocar, talvez é um ajuste trivial aonde a ordenação fica, por favor poste ele pra mim ver!

Comment: Esse é o meu Object real as chaves devem ser reordenadas conforme o titulo que está marcado na imagem: http://imgur.com/a/5gGPr

Comment: Convertendo o Object principal para um array e aplicando sua função funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Entendo que essa resposta cabe para o seu caso @LeoLetto. No caso, no final, só transformar o array em objeto. Porque a única solução para ordenar objetos é transformar as chaves em array e depois voltar ao original convertidos (para ordenar as chaves de um obj por exemplo).

Comment: @LeoLetto são varias chaves e dentro vários arrays de objetos, se precisa ordernar todos?

Comment: Sim, mas transformando o Object principal em um array e aplicando sua função funcionou bem : http://imgur.com/a/6Dn8n

Comment: Poxa @LeoLetto verdade agora funfo certinho.